# Why can I make a REST API request from a browser but not from Angular's resource?

Tags: angularjs, cors

Why can I make a REST API request from a browser/Postman/ even Node.js (http.get method), but not from Angular resource?

The snippet of the error message is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example-of-external-api-site.com 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Before asking this, I tried to look at the definition of CORS. And from my understanding, I can understand why it disallow the request I make from Angular's resource since it is coming from a different domain. But, isn't my browser/Postman/Node.js app are from a different domain as well?

Please help me answering this, I can't really understand why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request is made from the browser when accessing a url directly, you are requesting the content of a url without the use of `XMLHttpRequest`.

There are two scenarios for `$http.get()`:

When accessing a uri that is NOT the same domain that is hosting your AngularJS content, via an ajax call utilizing `XMLHttpRequest` from within the rendered content of your browser, you must provide a CORs header that matches the whitelisting on the target server.  This is due to browser security restrictions to prevent nasty, malicious attacks such as Cross Site Scripting.

When accessing a uri that IS the same domain as that which is hosting your AngularJS content (typically done via relative paths: `/Api/1` instead of `http://domain.com/api/1`), CORs whitelisting is not required, since both the origin and the target domain are the same.

Finally, when invoking a url from node, you are making a server to server concurrent call which does not have the same security restrictions since it is not executing within your browser.

Comment: Can you rephrase this paragraph `When accessing a uri via $http.get(), you are requesting resources from a domain other than that hosting your AngularJS content, via an ajax call utilizing XMLHttpRequest from within the rendered content of your browser. When you do this, you must provide a CORs header that matches the whitelisting on your server, per browser security restrictions.` ? I'm in an assumption that when I do $http.get, I'm requesting resources from a domain that is hosting my AngularJS content.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect, based on the error message that you have posted.  You are requesting a resource at `http://example-of-external-api-site.com` via `XMLHttpRequest`, hence the CORs issue.  You would only be assured of requesting resources from the same domain that is hosting your content if you were always requesting via relative paths.

Comment: I understand how the CORS issue exist by requesting a resource to `example-of-external-api-site.com` via XMLHttpRequest from my domain. What I want to clarify is the wording `from a domain other than that hosting your AngularJS content`

Comment: Sorry, English is my second language, and I think I understand what you are trying to explain.

Comment: No problem and my apologies if I haven't clarified properly.  Please see my updated answer.  I've expanded on my comments.